# Error loading and running event receiver Could not load file or assembly CUSTOM DLL The system cannot find the file specified.

Tags: visual-studio, event-receivers

I have created an EventReceiver that references a library I created in the same Solution (2 different projects). Whenever I add an item to the associated list I see this error in the log:

> 09/07/2012 15:29:19.20    ScriptEditor.exe (0x17BC)
>     0x1668  SharePoint Foundation           General
>     6875    Critical    Error loading and running event receiver
>   PAR_NPI.ParSendComments.ParSendComments in PAR_NPI, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e49bc376710d17a9. Additional
>   information is below.  : Could not load file or assembly
>   'WCWC.SharePointExtensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9547592d373b2043' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I have ensured that the latest version of the dll is installed in the GAC. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might sound sill and you probably have done it but have you done an iis reset after putting the dll in GAC?

or if that doesnt help would this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406037/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

dont know if that will be much help to you but i hope it is!

Comment: I had done an IIS reset. I have not done the steps in the first link. I'll check that tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for the response!

Comment: The steps in this article http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/ (marking as a safe control) fixed it. The link was in one of the comments on your StackOverflow suggestion. A simple thing I had forgotten to do!

Comment: glad to see its helped you out :). Yes its seems to be common thing that alot of people seem to forget ;) , using wspbuilder it does it for you tho :)